# python: Google Street View url request cannot load as json()

Tags: python, json, api, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I want to use python to grab Google Street View image. 
For example:

```
'url=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=48.15763817939112,11.533002555370581&size=512x512&key=
```

I run the following code:

```
import requests
result = requests.get(url)
result.json()
```

But it comes out an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-69-180c2a4b335d>", line 1, in <module>
    result.json()

  File "/home/kang/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 826, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

  File "/home/kang/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 516, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "/home/kang/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)

  File "/home/kang/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

The response of this url is:

[image]

How to fix that?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you print the response that you are getting back. When I tried hitting this URL on my browser, I did not get a JSON response back. May be that is the error?

Comment: /home/kang/Desktop/streetview.jpg

Comment: Why are you giving link to your local file?

Comment: How to paste an image in the comment? I just download the response of this url. But in the image, it says 'Sorry, we do not have image here'

Comment: paste it over some image sharing website and you can give a link here. Or you can edit your question with the image. Or you can simply edit your question with actual response.

Comment: In python, I type the response like this:`print(r)
<Response [200]>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no JSON in the response that is coming back to you, which is why it is giving the error.

Answer (score 2):

There a new [Street View Image Metadata](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata) API that does return JSON.

It will let you query for the availability of Street View panoramas at given locations (by address or latlng). If a panorama is found, the response will include its pano IDs. These queries are free.

Otherwise, the Street View Image API will always return an image. That's why the above JSON metadata API was introduced.